# Select from one table plus AND

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure:

```
id  product_id  attribute_id    attribute_val_id

138     18          29          304
137     17          29          304
78      17          20          161
79      17          21          301
80      17          22          94
```

I want to select product Id (for example 17) which has attribute_val_id equal to: 304 and 161 and 301.

I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM `products_attribute_rel` 
WHERE attribute_val_id = 304 
AND attribute_val_id = 161 
AND attribute_val_id = 301
```

But with this I get empty results. MYSQL `IN` sentence also makes no good.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id
FROM products_attribute_rel 
WHERE attribute_val_id IN (161, 301, 304)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_val_id) >= 3;
```

You should have (attribute_val_id, product_id) index on the table to make the query faster.

Comment: I think the index would do better if it was (attribute_val_id,product_id) as it could then use it in the where clause but otherwise +1.

Comment: @Ben, that way the index won't be used for the grouping

Comment: I tested this on a 17m row table with a non-unique index on 2 cols. (product_id,attribute_val_id) returned `index full scan, sort group by, filter`, the index the other way round was `index range scan, sort group by, filter`. There was no need scan the entire index as the where clause was scanning for the first column in that index. As all the values you're collecting are in the index it was used for the grouping. Though of course it does depend how everything is set up.

Comment: @Ben, certaily, you are right, the (attribute_val_id,product_id) is much better. I do not know why I insisted on the opposite )

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.product_id 
FROM products_attribute_rel p1
INNER JOIN products_attribute_rel p2 on p1.product_id = p2.product_id
INNER JOIN products_attribute_rel p3 on p1.product_id = p3.product_id
WHERE p1.attribute_val_id = 304
  AND p2.attribute_val_id = 161
  AND p3.attribute_val_id = 301;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're trying to do?

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM products_attribute_rel
WHERE attribute_val_id = 304
AND product_id IN (
   SELECT product_id
   FROM products_attribute_rel
   WHERE attribute_val_id = 161
   AND product_id IN ( 
      SELECT product_id
      FROM products_attribute_rel
      WHERE attribute_val_id = 301
   )
);
```

Haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 0):

No way 1 field can have multiple values, use `OR` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM `products_attribute_rel` 
WHERE attribute_val_id = 304 
OR attribute_val_id = 161 
OR attribute_val_id = 301
```

Comment: I think that's not what he wants.

Comment: This query will also return `18` which is not required as I see and understand the question.